# Datepicker works with browser Google Chrome but not with firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is My Modal

```
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime DO_Joining { get; set; }
```

Tha Date Picker works properly with out applying any DatePicker or JQuery to it in Google Chorme, but not working in Firefox. Can any body explain what is the matter .?

This is My view

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DO_Joining)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DO_Joining)


        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DO_Joining)
    </div>
```

And using these bundles

```
{
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/datepick/ts_picker.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
}
```

}
 But i really don't know ... what to do with this

Comment: That's simply a C# property declaration, it has nothing to do with MVC, jquery, HTML or even validation. Please provide your HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `@Html.EditorFor()` for a property decorated with `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` results in `<input ... type="date" />` which renders the browsers version of a HTML5 datepicker.

This is only supported in some modern browsers, and not at all in FireFox. [Refer comparison here](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-39/firefox-34/opera-24.html)

Side note: In order for the datepicker to correctly render the value of `DO_Joining`, you must also use the ISO format (otherwise there are inconsistent output across various browsers which do support it). And you don't need the `[Required]` attribute (unless your `DateTime?` - i.e. nullable)

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime DO_Joining { get; set; }
```

Comment: here i already using Html.EditorFor() and also i past your code in my modal, but still it works in google Chrome but  not in firefox, what i should to do more, so that it may work in firefox too.

Comment: I know your using `EditorFor()`. Read my answer again carefully. The second paragraph!

Comment: can you plz explain ... what should i do with it.. don't know.. what you want to say.